# Horizontal line overlapped by colored cells in table

Tags: color, tabularx, multirow

I am unable to get a horizontal line visible after I have applied color to the cells. Also, the text "After Fault Clearance" doesn't seem to be vertically centered. Below is a sample of my problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage{booktabs,multicol,multirow,bigstrut}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{5pt}
\scriptsize
\centering
\caption{ACR Status}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|c|c|Y|Y|Y|}
\hline
\cellcolor{blue!30}  &\cellcolor{blue!30} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c|}  {\cellcolor{blue!30}\textbf{Status}} \bigstrut[b]\\            
\cline{3-5} \multirow{-2}[0]{*}{\cellcolor{blue!30} \textbf{No.}} 
& \multirow{-2}[0]{*}{\cellcolor{blue!30} \textbf{ACR}} 
& \cellcolor{blue!30} \textbf{Before Fault}
& \cellcolor{blue!30}\textbf{During  Fault} 
& \cellcolor{blue!30}\textbf{After Fault Clearance} \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    1     & ACR1  & 1     & 0     & 1 \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    2     & ACR2  & 1     & 0     & 1 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    3     & ACR3  & 0     & 1     & 0 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    4     & ACR4  & 1     & 1     & 1 \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    5     & ACR5  & 1     & 1     & 1 \bigstrut[t]\\
    \hline
    \end{tabularx}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: as documented in the colortbl documentation the colour panels will always overlap `\cline` you could use `\hhline` from the package of the same name, instead.

Comment: In my working example above, I am not using the colortbl package. Is this really necessary? If yes, I'm not sure how to go about it also.

Comment: @pyro Yes you are. `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` will load `colortbl`.

Comment: I see...tq for pointing that out. Still figuring out how to work this out. My skills are not up to mark unfortunately.